# Angular AuthGuard with NGRX

Tags: angular, authentication, store, ngrx

I am trying to use the AuthGuard with NGRX, but i always get undefined on this route:

When i look at Store, the estaAutenticado is true, but i cant get on time, because its async?

My guard:

````
     return this.store.pipe(
       select(fromAuth.getEstaAutenticado ),
       map(authed => {
       console.log(authed) // <---- Always return undefined
         if (!authed) {
           this.router.navigate(['/'])
           return false;
         }
         return true;
       })
     );
   }
 ```
// Reducer
````

```
    export interface State {
        usuario: Usuario,
        estaAutenticado: boolean,
        erro: string
    }

    export const initialState: State = {
        usuario: null,
        estaAutenticado: false,
        erro: ''
    };

    export const getUsuario = (state: State) => state.usuario;
    export const getEstaAutenticado = (state: State) => state.estaAutenticado;
    export const getErro = (state: State) => state.erro;
```

Comment: try add `filter(authed => typeof authed !== 'undefined')` before map

Comment: wheres the `createReducer` code?

Comment: @SWilko which part?

Comment: @PrzemyslawJanBeigert i got the same result, the action is dispatched i got the login success, but i still receiving undefined there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I was missing the selectorFeature

```
export const selecionaState = createFeatureSelector<State>('autenticacao');
```